# Skip for loop when if statement is met inside for loop

Tags: if-statement, arduino, breakpoints

I have an `if` statement inside a `for` loop. When the the condition in `if` statement is true, I want to break out of the `for` loop.

here is what exactly I have

```
if (data < voltage && data2 < voltage) {
digitalWrite(pump, HIGH);
digitalWrite(valve, HIGH);
digitalWrite(valve2, HIGH);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
  lcd.print("S_1:");
  if (data > 260 && data < 295)
    lcd.print("MID");
  else if (data < 260)
    lcd.print("LOW");
  else
    lcd.print("HIGH");
  lcd.setCursor(7, 0);
  lcd.print("Pump:ON");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("V1:ON");
  lcd.setCursor(9, 2);
  lcd.print("S_2:");
  if (data2 > 260 && data2 < 295)
    lcd.print("MID");
  else if (data2 < 260)
    lcd.print("LOW");
  else
    lcd.print("HIGH");
  lcd.setCursor(7, 1);
  lcd.print("V2:ON");
  lcd.setCursor(14, 1);
  lcd.print("V3:OFF");
  sum += data;
  sum2 += data2;
  delay(1000);
}
average = sum / 10;
average2 = sum2 / 10;
if (average > voltage || average2 > voltage) {
  digitalWrite(pump, LOW);
  digitalWrite(valve, LOW);
  digitalWrite(valve2, LOW);
}
sum = 0;
sum2 = 0;
lcd.clear();
}
```

It seams not going throw the whole conditions.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the break keyword.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  if (i == 2){
    break;
  }
}
```

Also, this is considered by OOD people a gotoish code, prefer inserting the break condition in the for condition :

```
boolean shouldBreak = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 100 && !shouldBreak; i++){
  if (i == 2){
    shouldBreak = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, a `break` is probably as gotoish as a return statement within an `if`. Apart from this, the first approach is much more readable, so I would recommend using the tools the language provides you with.

Comment: I highly suggest you to read Dijkstra one-entry-point and one-exit-point view on structured programming.

Comment: I did, but I cannot say that I am the same opinion as he is when it comes to one exit point. If you need to resort to superfluous boolean variables just to replace a well placed `return` statement, then in my opinion it's the wrong way to go.

Comment: Well, my point is more likely "review your design" before doing either version of the code you or I suggested. Gotoish code tends to make work harder since you got to understand the possible context bump on a big legacy app.

Comment: Agreed, if you need to make frequent early returns, then maybe a refactoring is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `break;` keyword to do that.